# SVG intellisense in .vue files for vscode

Tags: vue.js, svg, visual-studio-code

I'm currently wanting to create Vue components with SVG elements as part of the template with the Vue components being created within `.vue` files. I am trying to work out how to get both IntelliSense for Vue from vetur as well as getting suggestions for SVG.

I have tried setting the file associations in the VsCode `settings.json` file, but it doesn't look like you can associate a file type to more than one language mode at a time.

Is it possible to use two different plugins for IntelliType on one file type or does that functionality not exist yet?